# React Stale State with Custom Hook Event Handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

It seems I just can't get my head around stale state issues in React as it relates to event handlers and hooks. I conceptually understand what is happening–there is a closure that is capturing the starting value of a state value, and isn't updating when I expect it to.

I am creating a NavBar component onto which I want to add keyboard controls to allow accessibility for sub menus and so forth. I will show the code and then describe what is happening / not happening. I'll also link to a codesandbox for easier forking and debugging.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-framework-iunvc?file=/src/App.tsx)

**NavBar**

```
const NavBar: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, label }) => {
  const {
    actions: { createNavItemRef },
    state: { activeSubMenuIndex, navBarRef },
  } = useNav();

  console.log('NAV.BAR', { activeSubMenuIndex });

  return (
    <nav aria-label={label} ref={navBarRef}>
      <NavList aria-label={label} role="menubar">
        {children} // NavItems
      </NavList>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

**NavItem**

```
const NavItem: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, hasSubMenu, to }) => {
  const ChildrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const {
    actions: { handleSelectSubMenu },
    state: { activeSubMenuIndex },
  } = useNav();

  const handleSubMenuToggle = () => {
    handleSelectSubMenu(index);
  };

  return (
    <li ref={ref} role="none">
      <>
        <ParentButton
          aria-expanded={activeSubMenuIndex === index}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={handleSubMenuToggle}
          role="menuitem"
          tabIndex={index === 0 ? 0 : -1}
        >
         {ChildrenArray.shift()}
        </ParentButton>
        {ChildrenArray.pop()}
      </>
    </li>
  );
};
```

**UseNav**

```
function useNav() {
  const navBarRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);    
  const [activeSubMenuIndex, setActiveSubMenuIndex] = useState<number | undefined>();

  const handleSelectSubMenu = (index?: number) => {
    if (!index || activeSubMenuIndex === index) {
      setActiveSubMenuIndex(undefined);
    } else {
      setActiveSubMenuIndex(index);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const navbar = navBarRef?.current;

    navbar?.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
      console.log("UseNav", { activeSubMenuIndex });
    });

    // return () => remove event listener
  }, [navBarRef, activeSubMenuIndex]);

  return {
    actions: {
      createNavItemRef,
      handleSelectSubMenu,
    },
    state: {
      activeSubMenuIndex,
      navBarRef,
    },
  };
}
```

This is a somewhat stripped down version of my set up. Ultimately, here's what's going on.

**Expectation**
I tab onto the first `NavItem` and it becomes focused. I hit an arrow key (for example) and the log `UseNav { activeSubMenuIndex })` logs out correctly as `undefined`.

Then I click on the NavItem which contains a sub menu. The `activeSubMenuIndex` updates and in the `NavItem` the correct sub menu is displayed (based on the `activeSubMenuIndex === index` conditional).

However, I would expect the `NavBar { activeSubMenuIndex })` to log out as well when this NavItem is clicked. But it doesn't.

With the sub menu visible, I hit another arrow key and when the `UseNav` log is displayed, I would expect it to contain the correct `activeSubMenuIndex` value, but it is still `undefined`.

Ultimately, I will need to addEventListeners for `keyPress` on the NavBar in order to assign keyboard navigation throughout. But if I can't even get the state values updating correctly at this MVP level, then I can't really move forward without making this more cumbersome to work with and debug later.

I know this is an issue of stale state, but I can't find any good articles on this topic that isn't just incrementing a number within the same file. So any help in finally cracking through this wall would be amazing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue stemmed from the use of the `useNav()` hook. When I call this hook inside of `NavBar` references and values are instantiated once. When I call the hook again in `NavItem` those same refs and values are instantiated again.

In this case, instead of a hook, it would make more sense to wrap this in a context in order to keep the logic out from the UI but keep the components consistent in their data sources.